# Get Top 5 Results by Difference Between Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if this is even possible to do purely with MySQL.

A top 5 list that is ordered as most improved between 2 different entries of the same data-point.

```
id     | year     | amount
-------+----------+--------
1      | 2016     | 4000
1      | 2017     | 3000
2      | 2016     | 12000
2      | 2017     | 15000
3      | 2016     | 100
3      | 2017     | 200
```

I essentially need it to return the `2` and `3`, in that order, since `2` improved more than `3`.

`1` should not be a result since it has not improved between years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check it here: http://rextester.com/TBX28881

```
select      f1.id, (f2.amount - f1.amount) balance
from        foot f1
inner join  foot f2
on          f2.id = f1.id
and         f2.year = 2017
where       f1.year = 2016
order by    balance desc
limit       5;
;

id | balance
---- --------
 2    3000
 3     100
 1   -1000
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to join the table to itself.

```
SELECT y1.id, (y1.amount - y0.amount) AS improvement
FROM yrtable AS y1
JOIN yrtable AS y0 ON y0.id = y1.id
WHERE y0.year = y1.year + 1
    AND y0.amount > y1.amount
ORDER BY (y1.amount - y0.amount)
```